# How to add menu into error task of visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, extensibility

I am building a Visual Studio extension to do some checks on a custom xaml file. Errors that are detected are displayed in the Error List.

Is it possible to extend the context menu of an ErrorTask item in the Error List of Visual studio? i want to add automatic correction functionality to our extension.(i want an option on clicking on ErrorTask)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I got it.. just used id **IDM_VS_CTXT_ERRORLIST**